# RAM for Kali Linux 1.0.9 VMWare 32 bit (i486)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, x86

How much RAM is the [Kali Linux 1.0.9 VMWare 32 bit (i486)](http://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) pre-configured to use. I have been searching on Google and various sites and cannot find the answer. I have limited, slow internet and need to know how much RAM it is pre-configured with so I can make sure to purchase the correct hosting account with the necessary amount of RAM to make sure the image works correctly.

The direct download link is [here](http://images.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-1.0.9-vm-i486.7z), but the first link I posted lists all the available images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and downloaded the image. The VMWare image in question is pre-configured to use 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jasonwryan, thanks, this is the complete answer to the question. I just need to wait about 16 hours to accept it as the correct answer.